# python socket listener not receiving data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming

I am programming a decentralised script to track the IPs of other computers running the script, to explore decentralisation. This script isolates the problem. The code consists of 2 scripts, one main program which sends its IP to an IP provided if one is provided, and a listener program which is run as a subscript and listens for data and pipes that data back to the main program. The main script appears to be working, the data is sent over the network, but the listener does not receive it.

This is the main script

```
    import socket
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    from time import sleep
    def getIP():
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        try:
            s.connect(('8.8.8.4', 1))
            IP = s.getsockname()[0]
        except Exception:
            IP = '127.0.0.1'
        finally:
            s.close()
        return IP
    def sendfyi(target, ownIP):
        toSend = 'fyi' + ':' + ownIP
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((target, 50000))
        s.send(toSend.encode())
        s.close()
        print('sent fyi')
    otherIPs = []
    ownIP = getIP()
    
    targetIP = input('enter ip or 0: ')
    if targetIP != '0':
        otherIPs.append(targetIP)
        sendfyi(targetIP, ownIP)
    
    listener = Popen(['python3', 'testlistener.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    i = 0
    while i == 0:
        sleep(1)
        listenerPipe = listener.stdout.readline()
        print(listenerPipe)
```

This is the sub process:

```
import socket
def getIP():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('8.8.8.4', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except Exception:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((getIP(), 50000))
i = 1
while i == 1:
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('conected', flush=True)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('data receved', flush=True)
    out = data.decode()
    print('data decoded', flush=True)
    print(out, flush=True)
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorect bind statement

```
bind(('', 50000))
```